# How to set job permissions from REST API?

Tags: databricks

I am creating automated cluster jobs on Databricks with a service account as part of an ingestion pipeline. I would like to give permissions to certain users so they can monitor the job's progress (e.g. view the Spark UI, logs and metrics). However I cannot find the related configuration option in the `2.0/jobs/create` endpoint. See [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/api/latest/jobs.html#create).

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across the same problem of setting permissions to the databricks job from REST API but the api currently not supported this feature. But there is a preview available and its not released officially.
url: https://baseuri/api/2.0/preview/permissions/jobs/jobid
http: patch
jobid: your job id
body:
{"access_control_list" : [{"user_name" : "" || "group_name" : "" ||
"service_principal_name" : "","permission_level" : "}]
}

Comment: I thik this is an Databricks issue, it shold have an monitoring role, please support this feature request https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/9ffc7b52-88eb-ed11-a81c-0022485030d1

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find to find an undocumented `2.0/jobs/reset-acl` endpoint. This can be used to assign permissions to an existing job

```
curl -X POST https://db-cluster/api/2.0/jobs/reset-acl \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $DATABRICKS_API_TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data '{ "job_id": 123, "grants":[{"user_id": 2345, "permission": "MANAGE_RUN"}, {"user_id": 3456, "permission": "IS_OWNER"}]}'
```

As this endpoint is not documented anywhere, I'd refrain from using it. However, the only other option I could find is to set it from the UI manually, which is not an acceptable work around for our use case.